# Django: Render text and link from a textfield in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am new to web development and currently building a blog.
I am trying to render some text that I wrote in a textfield inside the database.
The problem is that this text includes a link that links to another blog article.

`This is the textfield from "redirect" in Articles model`

```
Some text I want to render in blog with a link <a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/articles/8-Photogenic-Spiral-Staircases" class="link-within">8 Photogenic Spiral Staircases</a>
```

`html`

```
<p class="article-redirect">{{ article.redirect|safe|escape }}</p>
```

The HTML is successfully rendered using `|safe` filter but when I click on the link it displays a 404 error, the requested URL in the error message is

```
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/articles/7-Photogenic-Spiral-Staircases%7B%7B%20STATIC_URL%20%7D%7D/articles/8-Photogenic-Spiral-Staircases
```

In the above requested URL that caused the error, "7-Photogenic-Spiral-Staircases" is the current blog post and "8-Photogenic-Spiral-Staircases" is the blog post that I want to jump to.

Can someone help me understand why this is not working and what could be the possible solution?

`models.py`

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    redirect = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

`views.py`

```
def article(request, slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Articles, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'article': article,
    }
    return render(request, 'articletemplate.html', context)
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("articles/<str:slug>/", views.article, name="articles")
]
```

Comment: i updated my answer try it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update go to another link from an other page** 
if you want to render a link from your current page to an other page.
try this

```
Some text I want to render in blog with a link <a href="http://localhost:8000/articles/7-Photogenic-Spiral-Staircases" class="link-within">8 Photogenic Spiral Staircases</a>
```

i use actually the actual host name (the local host) this should work.

**The problem**

it is not working for you because you have not add the host name inside your link ,if you do not add that then django will take the current url + whatever you write inside that link and it won't be able to understand this variable `{{ STATIC_URL }}`.one of the possible solution for this is to use full url that you want to redirect inside the link `href`

**Solution**
models.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    redirect = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    recommendations = models.ManyToManyField("Articles",null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('articles',args=[self.slug])
```

`1)python manage.py makemigrations`
`2)python manage.py migrate`
`3)now inside your django admin you can add inside recommendations any article related to the current one.`
`4)now inside your redirect field you can just add a text saying like 'if you want to learn more about this topic please refer to'` 
template:

```
    <p class="article-redirect">{{ article.redirect }} <br>
{% for i in article.recommendations.all %}
 <a href="{{ i.get_absolute_url }}">{{ i.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

Comment: Hello @amadou thanks for your input. Yes I want to link to a different page from the blog post. And I want to be able to write the link in the database. If I use "http://localhost:8000" I would have to change them all in production right? I thought there might be a better way

Comment: @haashe yes you have to change them in production that's right.

Comment: @haashe why do you wanna redirect from an article to an other article are you implementing a recommendation article or what ?

Comment: something like a recommendation article. I want to reference some articles inside the blog post for further details on topics.

Comment: @haashe let me think how we can do it.